# WPF StackPanel Layout Question

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

I'm trying to create a layout similar to this:

[alt text http://img20.imageshack.us/img20/3533/stackn.png](http://img20.imageshack.us/img20/3533/stackn.png)

Here's the code I have:

```
<StackPanel TextBlock.FontFamily="Segoe UI" Orientation="Horizontal">
    <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Width="Auto">
        <TextBlock Padding="5,0,5,0" FontSize="12" FontWeight="Bold" Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Title}" />
        <TextBlock Padding="5,0,5,0" FontSize="12" Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Id}" />
    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Padding="5,0,5,0" FontSize="10" Text="Delete">
            <TextBlock.Style>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
                        </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </TextBlock.Style>    
        </TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Padding="5,0,5,0" FontSize="10" Text="Move">
            <TextBlock.Style>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
                        </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </TextBlock.Style>    
        </TextBlock>
    </StackPanel>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: where is the question, you have?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Why don't you use a Grid for this?

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="300" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <StackPanel Grid.Column="0">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" />
    </StackPanel>

    <StackPanel Grid.Column="1">        
        <TextBlock Text="Move" />
    </StackPanel>

</Grid>
```

Comment: Perfect! I never knew you could use an asterisk as width. 

Thanks!

Comment: The `<ColumnDefinition Width="*" />` is equivalent to `<ColumnDefinition />`

Comment: Also known as `<ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />`

Answer (score 3):

I think you might be better off with a grid as your parent element.  Omitting your styles and what not, here's the XAML for the layout in your drawing.

```
<Grid>
   <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
      <ColumnDefinition Width="50" />  <!-- or some other fixed width -->
   </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

   <StackPanel Grid.Column="0">
     <!-- left hand stackpanel content -->
   </StackPanel>
   <StackPanel Grid.Column="1">
      <!-- right hand StackPanel content -->
   </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Seems to output the same layout =/

Answer (score 1):

You don't really want a StackPanel for your red container.  I'd go with a DockPanel, dock the rightmost blue panel to the right, and ensure LastChildFill is on to ensure the leftmost blue panel expands to the window width.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code for what I get from your post:

```
<DockPanel TextBlock.FontFamily="Segoe UI" LastChildFill="True">
    <StackPanel DockPanel.Dock="Right">
        <TextBlock Padding="5,0,5,0" FontSize="10" Text="Delete">
        <TextBlock.Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </TextBlock.Style>
        </TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Padding="5,0,5,0" FontSize="10" Text="Move">
        <TextBlock.Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </TextBlock.Style>
        </TextBlock>
    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Width="Auto">
        <TextBlock Padding="5,0,5,0" FontSize="12" FontWeight="Bold" Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Title}" />
        <TextBlock Padding="5,0,5,0" FontSize="12" Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Id}" />
    </StackPanel>
</DockPanel>
```

Hope this helps!!